# How to process JSON Array of objects using Key values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

Here is the following JSON data I want to process in JavaScript

```
    let data = [{"Test1":"121"},{"isStats":"false"},{"isKey":"true"},{"Test2":"326"}]


Required data formate

processedData = [{name: "Test1", value: "121"},{name:"isStats", value:"false"},{name:"isKey", value:"true"},{name:"Test2", value:"326"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` like the below code:

```js
let data = [{"Test1":"121"},{"isStats":"false"},{"isKey":"true"},{"Test2":"326"}];

const processedData = data.map((element, index) => {
  const key = Object.keys(element)[0];
  return {
    name: key,
    value: element[key]
  }
});

console.log(processedData);
```

Comment: How can we revert this to the original formate @tartarus ?